# Unity2D - Why does the object rotate around the X/Y axis rather than the Z

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate an object to face another in Unity 2D. However i am having some trouble wrapping my head around the way unity uses 2D transformations and most examples I can find are designed for 3D.

Using the code below I can make the object rotate to face the right direction, however it also rotates the object so that it is the Z axis that is pointing towards it. Ideally the object would rotate around the Z axis.

```
rigidbody2D.transform.LookAt(currentlyTargeted.transform.position);
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried to set the worldUp parameter and check how it behaves? http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: Thanks, I diddnt realize that existed. However I have tried every combination of Vector3's (up,forward,down,left,right) and I still seem to have the same problem. The Z axis points to the object. `rigidbody2D.transform.LookAt(currentlyTargeted.transform.position, Vector3.up);`

Comment: On similar issues, I always found up that I had my object set incorrectly, or forgot I've transformed it beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently with LookAngle - please notice these functions take two arguments (the second one defaults to Vector3.up) - what did the trick for me is to call LookAngle like this:

```
LookAngle(Vector3.forward, myCalculatedPositionsDifference)
```

Maybe it will also help in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your object's direction in the mesh/sprite is rotated correctly, or place the object in a dummy object used to offset the rotation to the X/y axes